# Select Data using subquery in linq select statment

Tags: linq, lambda

I have a linq query which returns the correct data to me for all fields.

```
var data= (from p in table1
                        select new ViewModel
                        {                          
                            AgentFirstName = p.AspNetUser.UserAdditionalDatas.Where(c => c.UserId == p.userId).Select(c => c.FirstName).FirstOrDefault() + " " + p.AspNetUser.UserAdditionalDatas.Where(c => c.UserId == p.userId).Select(c => c.LastName).FirstOrDefault(),
                            AgentCompanyName = p.AspNetUser.UserAdditionalDatas.Where(c => c.UserId == p.userId).Select(c => c.Company).FirstOrDefault(),                           
                        }).ToList();
```

The issue is with "**AgentCompanyName**" field.It display the **ID** of the company instead of name.How I can achieve the desired result.I don't have any relation with company table.
Here is the screenshot of data I am getting for company.
http://prntscr.com/a1dobe

Please help me in this.

Comment: Well, you're selecting the `Company` field into that property.  Does that field contain the ID?  If so, select the field that contains the Name instead.

Comment: The field contains the ID.you are right.I think i have to join that ID to the company table in select statement.Am i right?

Comment: Ideally the object would either have the property you want or have a navigation property to link to an object with the property you want.  But I can't really know, it's your code.  If there's no navigation property then a join would probably be in order, yes.